# Getting indextOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, comparator

Ifdsfafadsfasd few fv afwqf adsfdfadfsafdsafewfdsfsdfdsfsfwefds safsda
     {fdsfasd

```
     int foundIndex = Collections.binarySearch(keys, key, 

     return foundIndex;
 }


 public int compareTo(K otherKey) 
 {
  int result = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
  {
      result = ((Comparable<K>) keys.get(i)).compareTo(otherKey);
  }
  return result;
 }
}
```

Failling test case:

```
@Test(timeout=1000) public void faals_order1(){
    IMiniMap<String,Integer> map = new<String,Integer>();

    assertEquals(al("Luigi","Mario","Peach","Toad"),map.keys());
    assertEquals(al(2,1,3,4), map.values());
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? Most debuggers will let you set a breakpoint on a particular type of exception.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check the returned value from `indexOf` to ensure the value is found.  `indexOf` will return -1 if the value isn't present

Comment: I shouln't get that though, @MrWiggles. I've added the small test case in the code

Comment: Why doesn't it catch the RuntimeException though? @MrWiggles

Comment: Sorry - my bad - it's not -1 you're looking for, it's current list size() as binarySearch can return that

Comment: Nope, now I've seen your test case this is the case.  Your indexOf method is returning -1

Comment: If you read the JavaDoc for `Collections.binarySearch` it states "the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1)".  On the first call your list is empty, so this will return -1, as the exception is telling you.

Comment: Yeah, but if the `key` is not in the list I would add that `key` into the sorted list which I'm trying to do, @MrWiggles

Comment: Exactly - the binarySearch will say "-1", as in this isn't in the list, so add it.